# Calling file() on pastebin URL fails, but on local file or google.com it works

Tags: php, fopen, remote-server, pastebin

I'm working on a bit of PHP code that depends on a remote file which happens to be hosted on pastebin. The server I am working on has all the necessary functions enabled, as running it with `FILE_URL` set to `http://google.com` returns the expected results. I've also verified through `php.ini` for extra measure.

Everything **should** work, but it doesn't. Calling `file()` on a URL formed as such, `http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=<paste id here>`, returns a 500 server error. Doing the same on the exact same file hosted locally or on google.com returns a reasonable result.

I have verified that the URL is set to the correct value and verified that the remote page is where I think that it is. I'm at a loss.

```
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", true);
// Prefer remote (up-to-date) file, fallback to local file
if( ini_get("allow_url_fopen") ){
    $file = file( FILE_URL );
}
if(!isset( $file ) || !$file ) {
    $file = file( LOCAL_FILE_PATH );
}
```

Comment: Very possible they are blocking you because you have unset header data or their is a redirect and your not being redirected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to test this, but you should use curl, try something like this:

```
<?php
$url = "http://pastebin.com/2ZdFcEKh";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Add `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` and raw code url of `pastebin.com`

Comment: I appreciate the help! With the contributions from @shiplu.mokadd.im this solution worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Pastebin appear to use a protection system that will automatically block IP addresses that issue requests that are "bot-like".

In the case of your example, you will get a 500 server error since the `file()` command never completes (since their protection system never closes the connection) and there is no timeout facility in your call. The script is probably considered "bot-like" since `file()` does not pass through all the standard HTTP headers a typical browser would.

To solve this problem, I would recommend investigating [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and perhaps look at [setting a browser user agent](http://davidwalsh.name/set-user-agent-php-curl-spoof) as a starting point to grant access to your script. I should also mention that it would be in your interests to investigate whether or not this is considered a breach of the Pastebin user agreement. While I cannot see any reference to using scripts in [their FAQ](http://pastebin.com/faq) (as of 2012/12/29), they have installed protection against scripts for a reason.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Did a little reading and they do have a published API, though it only covers publishing/editing pastes. I'm assuming from that that the reading of pastes is left up to the programmer to figure out.

Comment: You're most welcome. I think the banning aspect is covered by their protection service, which I believe is called ProxyShield. This is a layer that sits in front of their servers, protecting them against various DoS scenarios. I tried to look up information on the ProxyShield service, but found nothing substantial.